# The intersection of open normal subgroups in a compact, totally disconnected topological group is trivial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, topological-groups

I am currently doing self-study on profinite groups and I'm stuck trying to prove the following lemma.

> If a topological group $G$ is compact and totally disconnected, then the open normal subgroups of $G$ intersect in the trivial subgroup $\{\,1_{G}\,\}$.

While I hope that mere hints will allow me to see how to prove this, I think I may need someone to just spell-it-out for me.  I've been racking my brain as to how I could prove this and I've made little progress. Either way, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: See [An equivalent definition of the profinite group](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55539/an-equivalent-definition-of-the-profinite-group)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I have read that post several times, and while I see that it is *related* to my question, I still don't see how it helps me.

Comment: It gives you immediately the answer since Hausdorff spaces are accessible.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**  In a compact totally disconnected group $G$, the family of open 
invariant subgroups forms a local base at the neutral element of $G$.