# Open normal subgroups of a profinite group form a basis for the open neighborhoods of 1

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, profinite-groups

In the following link:
[An equivalent definition of the profinite group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55539/an-equivalent-definition-of-the-profinite-group?rq=1)
I'm having trouble understanding the following quote from the answer:

> So if you replace each subgroup in a basis by the intersection of its conjugates, you obtain a basis made up of normal subgroups.

How can one prove that these normal subgroups form a basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mathscr H$ is a local base of $1$, then $\{\bigcap_{x\in G} xHx^{-1}\mid H\in \mathscr H\}$ is a local base of $1$ because for every open neighborhood $A$ of $1$,  $1\in \bigcap_{x\in G} xHx^{-1}\subset H\subset A$ for some $H\in \mathscr H$. The fact that $\bigcap_{x\in G} xHx^{-1}\mid H$ is open is proven in your linked answer.

Comment: Thank you! on the same subject, can you please explain why must every open nbhd _subset_ $A$ of 1 contain a _subgroup_ $H$?

Comment: @Shmooze Because $\mathscr H$ is a basis. By definition, every open subset of $1$ contains a basis element in $\mathscr H$.