# Equivalent definition of profinite group

Tags: topological-groups, profinite-groups

Sorry for my bad English.

Let $G$ be a topological group, then we say $G$ is profinite if $G$ satisfies next equivalent condition as follow;

(i) $G$ is compact, Hausdorff, totally disconnected.

(ii)$G$ is compact, Hausdorff, unit element $1\in G$ has neighbourhood system　consisted of normal subgroup.

But I can't understand why there are equivalent. Please tell me this proof or reference or hint, thanks.

Comment: duplicate? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55539/an-equivalent-definition-of-the-profinite-group?rq=1

Comment: @LurchiDerLurch Is it same question? It seems question about "normal" condition.

Comment: You can find a proof in Theorem 2.1.3 of the book Profinite Groups, by L. Ribes and P. Zalesskii

Comment: You really should learn enough English to express questions unambiguously. The word "next" means "the first one that comes afterward" — but you mention *two*. Then you do not say whether you mean "(i) or (ii)" or "(i) and (ii)". Then you do not say that these are equivalent until you ask a question about that "fact".